# Run a Bash script if not Running

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, raspberry-pi, automated-tests

I have bash script sitting on linux device in the field. I want this script to be running 24/7. There are sometime just bad instances when my script would break because of reason not in my control. So, in that case I want this script to restart whenever it dies.

Any ideas or example code to get me going?

Comment: Create a systemd service for it then set `Restart=always` or `on-failure` depending on your use case.

Comment: There's also `forever` which can be installed ontop of `nodejs`. Which features a cli to manage/stop/start your forever scripts.

Comment: @iBug --- Awesome!!!. Your suggestion is really good and I feel like I can do much more than this task by creating my custom systemd services.

Comment: You could use [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/), which is a package on various linux systems (ubuntu and debian have it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your goal is exactly the function of a *service manager*, and systemd is the one that comes with Raspbian. You can create a systemd service for your script, set its restart mode to `always` (can only be stopped manually) or `on-failure` (restart when exits with failure).

You can create `/etc/systemd/system/my-script.service` with the following content:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=My Script

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /path/to/script.sh
#WorkingDirectory=somewhere if you need
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You then run `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl start my-script`.

If you need more customization, you can look up [the manual page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=) near `Restart=`.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [Cron](https://www.cherryservers.com/blog/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-linux-jobs-on-ubuntu-20-04#:%7E:text=in%20Linux%20community.-,What%20is%20Cron%3F,on%20a%20pre%2Dset%20schedule.).  It's a way to automate a script to run on a schedule.  Almost every Linux machine has [Crontab](https://www.cherryservers.com/blog/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-linux-jobs-on-ubuntu-20-04#:%7E:text=in%20Linux%20community.-,What%20is%20Cron%3F,on%20a%20pre%2Dset%20schedule.), so it shouldn't be hard to get started with a [couple of examples](https://crontab.guru/examples.html).